# templates conflicting type - yet types should be the same cfr class hierarchy?

Tags: c++

I have usb devices. I have

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<deviceTypeX>>> deviceTypeXMap;
```

to store the instances I create for the devices.

the class hierarchy is like usbdevice-deviceTypeX-specificDevice

so every specificDevice is-a deviceTypeX

deviceTypeX contains virtual functions that specificDevice needs to implement. usbdevice contains the generic usb things that all (my) devices have in common like a method to connect and the likes.

The idea is that the class that contains the above items (let's call it's instance 'usbdevices') will have public methods that'll allow writing to the hardware so that everything is abstracted away.

I have the following template in the 'usbdevices' header file:

```
template <typename classType>
void addInstance(std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<classType>>> &outer,
                             int outerKey, std::unique_ptr<classType> instanceToAdd, int innerKey) {
    auto outerSearch = outer.find(outerKey);
    if (outerSearch != outer.end()) {
        outerSearch->second.try_emplace(innerKey, std::move(instanceToAdd));
    }
    else{ //outer key not found }
}
```

to add instances.
I add them using a callback once a hotplug event occurs like this

```
addInstance(deviceTypeXMap, desc.idVendor, std::make_unique<specificDevice>(dev, ctx), desc.idProduct);
```

compilation fails with

In file included from .../hardware/usbdevices.cpp:5:0:
.../hardware/usbdevices.h:47:10: note: candidate: template void usbdevices::addInstance(std::unordered_map > >&, int, std::unique_ptr<_Tp>, int)
     void addInstance(std::unordered_map>> &outer,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
.../hardware/usbdevices.h:47:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
.../hardware/usbdevices.cpp:121:114: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘deviceTypeX’ and ‘specificDevice’)

Why are specificDevice and deviceTypeX conflicting? I'm learning templates... The approach described works if I don't use templates but obviously I need templates because otherwise I'll have to create multiple addInstance methods for deviceTypeX, deviceTypeY etc.

I don't understand it. What do I need to to do make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ templates only match the *exact* type given, without trying to find a type which is compatible. This is the cause of the error - `deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘deviceTypeX’ and ‘specificDevice’)`.

To solve this, you can make the function take 2 template parameters:

```
template <typename outerType, typename instanceType>
void addInstance(std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<outerType>>> &outer,
                             int outerKey, std::unique_ptr<instanceType> instanceToAdd, int innerKey) {
    auto outerSearch = outer.find(outerKey);
    if (outerSearch != outer.end()) {
        outerSearch->second.try_emplace(innerKey, std::move(instanceToAdd));
    }
    else{ //outer key not found }
}
```

The `instanceToAdd` will be converted in the body of the function when it is being emplaced.

Comment: It compiles now, runs and seems to be running correctly. Thank you for the clarification.